# backbone js render a view without a model and fetch model on view submit

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to change a nodeceller app from here:

https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar

I am trying to have a View where a user can enter a wine name into a simple form and, on submit, I fetch a model based on the wine id entered.

Basically a WineView form which has a deferred bind to a Wine model based on the wine id entered in the form.

Say I have a NewWineView which allows the user to enter a wine id and a new description for a wine. On form submit, I fetch the wine model by id and update it and return the response.

```
wineDetails: function (id) {
        // I dont have an ID of wine yet to fetch wine model
        var wine = new Wine({_id: id});
        wine.fetch({success: function(){
            $("#content").html(new WineView({model: wine}).el);
        }});
        this.headerView.selectMenuItem();
    }
```

I am new to backbonejs and I am trying to figure out how to create a view that is detached from a model and only attaches and updates one when a submit button is clicked in the view.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should separate your fetch and save actions.

Comment: They are separate as above code renders view after fetching.  After fetch save is triggered by click of save button on view. My trouble is I want to render a view with no model and based on ID field in view form I would like to internally fetch and bind corresponding model to view..